# Variable Not Showing Value

Tags: c#

I am running the below code, and if I step-thru the code it shows my value but when it gets to the

```
if (Directory.Exists(folderPath))
```

fName isn't being shown in the folderPath.  It only shows for example.

```
"\\\\Delta\\" + fName + "_Monday\\"
```

Can someone show me what I should update to get this to function properly?

```
public static void OpenExcelWorkbook()
{
    fName = new string[4] { "Mike", "Joe", "Hickney", "Rich", };
    folderPaths = new string[7] 
    {
        "\\\\Delta\\" + fName + "_Monday\\",
        "\\\\Delta\\" + fName + "_Tuesday\\",
        "\\\\Delta\\" + fName + "_Wednesday\\",
        "\\\\Delta\\" + fName + "_Thursday\\",
        "\\\\Delta\\" + fName + "_Friday\\",
        "\\\\Delta\\" + fName + "_Saturday\\",
        "\\\\Delta\\" + fName + "_Sunday\\",
    };
    fileNames = new string[4]
    {
        fName + "_generaldaily_file.xlsx",
        fName + "_employeeDaily_cumulative.xls",
        fName + "_generaldaily_file.xlsx",
        fName + "_employeeDaily_cumulative.xls",
        };

    Excel.Workbook wb = null;
    try
    {
        for (int q = fName.GetLowerBound(0); q <= fName.GetUpperBound(0); q++)
        {
            foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
            {
                foreach (string folderPath in folderPaths)
                {
                    if (Directory.Exists(folderPath))
                    {
                        foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(folderPath))
                        {
                            string temp = Path.GetFileName(filePath).ToLower();
                            if (temp == fileName.ToLower())
                            {
                                oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Open(folderPath + fileName));
                                oWB = oXL.ActiveWorkbook;
                                oWB.RefreshAll();
                                //Calling method to save workbook here
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: Where is fname declared? I do not see the code here.

Comment: I'll add that in, sure give me just a minute

Comment: `It only shows for example.
"\\\\Delta\\" + fName + "_Monday\\"`
What do you mean? How can any string show that?

Comment: If you see that back in the debugger then you fumbled the backslashes.  Like `"\\\\Delta\" + fName + \"_Monday\\"`.  Your code snippet doesn't show that problem.  Do favor using @ before the string.

Comment: What is the type of `oWB`? And are you intentionally overwriting it immediately after opening `folderPath + fileName` ?

Comment: fname is an array and you use it without indexing in the code.

Comment: @Tarec when I step through my code the value of folderPath will omit the value of fName.  Even though in the debug window it shows fName has an accurate value?

Comment: Try fname[0] instead.

Comment: @ThunderGr I think that he's trying to loop through _each_ fName for _each_ folder. If that's the case his control structure is valid

Comment: @ThunderGr --- Yes that is what I am attempting to do!

Comment: You are adding an array to a string... what exactly you expect to happen?

Comment: Take a look at the **DirectoryInfo** and **FileInfo** classes in **System.IO Namespace**.

Comment: @darkpbj He is defining an array of Strings(folderpaths) with fname in the initialization. It will not work.

Comment: @ThunderGr mea culpa, that's right--I didn't catch that the first time around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suggestion, use Path.Combine instead of manually concatenating directory names, and preferably use `@""` for string literals which avoids the need to escape backslashes. eg

```
Path.Combine(@"\\Delta", fName + "_Monday");
```

You shouldn't need to pre-generate the lists of pathnames and filenames as arrays, but just create them on-demand as you iterate through the list of names.

```
string root = @"\\Delta";

String[] dayOfWeek = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
String[] fileNames = { "generaldaily_file.xlsx", "employeeDaily_cumulative.xls", "generaldaily_file.xlsx", "employeeDaily_cumulative.xls" };
String[] fName = { "Mike", "Joe", "Hickney", "Rich" };

foreach (string name in fName) {
    foreach (string day in dayOfWeek)
        var folderPath = Path.Combine(root, name + "_" + day);
        if (Directory.Exists(folderPath)) {
            foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(folderPath) {
                string temp = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                foreach (string fileName in fileNames) {
                    if (temp.toLower() == (name + "_" + fileName).toLower()) {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, don't swallow up Exceptions with empty catch blocks, or you won't know what's wrong if something breaks. At minimum you should be printing or logging a stack trace so you can work out where the problems might be.

Comment: +1 for creating on demand. I do not think Path.Combine is necessary, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd refactor your code to he following since I don't see how you are assigning the value to fname it would be better if you pass that parameter explicitly

```
public static void OpenExcelWorkbook(string fName)
    {
        public string[] GetFolderPaths() 
        {
            return new string[7] = {
            string.format("\\\\Delta\\{0}_Monday\\",fName),
            string.format("\\\\Delta\\{0}_Tuesday\\",fName),
            string.format("\\\\Delta\\{0}_Wednesday\\",fName),
            string.format("\\\\Delta\\{0}_Thursday\\",fName),
            string.format("\\\\Delta\\{0}_Friday\\",fName),
            string.format("\\\\Delta\\{0}_Saturday\\",fName),
            string.format("\\\\Delta\\{0}_Sunday\\",fName)
            }
        };
       // the same applies to the filenames
        public string[] GetFileNames(){
            return new string[4] ={
            string.format("{0}_generaldaily_file.xlsx",fName),
            string.format("{0}_employeeDaily_cumulative.xls",fName),
            string.format("{0}_generaldaily_file.xlsx",fName),
            string.format("{0}_employeeDaily_cumulative.xls",fName)}

        }

        foreach (string fileName in GetFileNames())
        {
            foreach (string folderPath in GetFolderPaths())
            {
              // do your logic here
            }
        }
      }
```